# Secure RSA Exchange between two devices

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

lets say I have a keypart, that is created by Device A (in this case CryptoCard) the keypart should be stored on Device B (in this Case a SmartCard) and returned on demand. I thought of encrypting the keypart with the private key of a RSA and give Public Key to Device B. Device B could then decrypt it and Encrypt it with it's own Private Key store it and send it back encrypted when needed.

Now I'm wondering how I exchange the public keys to decrypt the keypart without loosing security. As it would be stupid to send secret and key side by side, as it's the same then sending the key decrypted, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal procedure would be:

1. Device B sends its public key to device A
2. Device A encrypts the secret with the public key of B and sends the result to B
3. Device B decrypts the secret with its private key.

The only tricky part is step 1, you must be absolutely sure that the public key is really from device B, but it is not necessary to keep it secret.

Comment: "you must be absolutely sure that the public key is really from device B" -- exactly, there is a trivial man-in-the-middle attack if you do not verify that the key belongs to the device that claims it.  In order to prevent this, a common solution is to sign public keys with a root authority key.  The root public key needs to be in all the devices so that the devices can verify the public keys of other devices.

Comment: @TheGreatContini Using a certification authority actually just moves the burden of key verification to it. It does not change the principal problem. It really depends on the setup of the whole system which way is easier and more secure.

Comment: @Henrry You'r reading too much into my comment.  A full PKI design with  Certificate authorities is overkill.  Instead, just a single root key that has the public key embedded in every manufactured device.  This is a very common solution in embedded security.  The device needs to do no further verification because the public key is embedded as part of its firmware.

Comment: @Henry A small Question furthermore: As my encrypted File is a key part to build a key in a cryptocard, somebody could steel the encrypted keypart and use this encrypted one to build the key in the crypto card so there is no difference between encrytpted/decrypted message trasnfer, no?

Comment: @Florian Don't get it, how can the encrypted key part be used to build the key if it cannot be decrypted? Or do the crypto cards all share the same key pair? (they shouldn't)

Comment: @Henry That's the Question, let's say we have a key (from Cryptocard) split up in 4 keyparts, they are distributed on 4 smartcards. we need two of them to build the key in the cryptocard. So the thoughts of my original question was how to secure exchange this keyparts between cryptocard and the two smartcards.

Comment: Ok got it... the cryptocard creates a new keypair everytime it requests a keypart

Answer (score -1):

You can let B encrypt the key using it's private key, and send it to A, so that A can decrypt it using B's public key, this ensures non-repudiation and the key is definitely from B.

Comment: A self-signed key can be produced by a man-in-the middle. This doesn't ensure anything.

Comment: ah, the signed key can be captured and replayed, yes, i agree. i agree with the above accepted solution where it was suggesting the use of a root authority (CA).